# Use Firebase ML Vision to detect spots / dots / circles in an image

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-machine-learning

I'm using the firebase_ml_vision plugin for flutter. I need to detect all the spots / dots / solid circles on an image. With the example app, and using cloudImageLabeler i managed to detect that there are circles in the image with confidence of 75%+ but i dont know how to detect how many there are.

Ex.
If there are 5 dots on a piece of paper, i need to be able to show a count of 5

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using firebase_ml_custom. After we trained a custom model, and uploaded it to firebase console we managed to detect the dots.

We trained the model to recognise the dots, loaded the model with the Tflite plugin. Then with Tflite.detectObjectOnImage we could get the list of all the "labels" / detected objects.